# Check box not working on form before allowed to submit

Tags: javascript, html, button, checkbox, submit

Hello guys trying to get my checkbox to need to be clicked before submitting my button which is an onclick not submit??

```html
<form>
  <p>
    <input style="padding:14px; -webkit-border-radius: 30px; -moz-border-radius: 30px; border-radius: 30px; width: 300px; border: none;" placeholder="Enter Date Here... e.g 17/05/1981" />
  </p>

  <p>

    <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle3" name="vehicle3" value="Boat" required="true"> <label style="color: #fff; font-size: 10px;"> Please Accept Terms</label></p>

  <p><a id="generateButton" href="generate.html" class="progress-button red" data-loading="Creating..." data-finished="Start Over" data-type="background-vertical" onclick="getRandomImage()">Start Search</a></p>
</form>
```

Comment: You can write a custom JS function to validate whether the checkbox is checked. There were many answers in the stackoverflow

Comment: Check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h2rfatgm/)

Comment: i have my own button see my code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately HTML5 does not provide an out-of-the-box way to do that.

However, using jQuery, or javascript, you can easily control if a checkbox group has at least one checked element.

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myCheck").required = true;
}
```

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
  Checkbox: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" name="test">
  <input type="submit" onclick="myFunction()">
</form>
```

Comment: this doesnt work i have my own button

Comment: <a id="generateButton" href="generate.html" class="progress-button red" data-loading="Creating..." data-finished="Start Over" data-type="background-vertical" onclick = "getRandomImage()">Start Search</a>

Comment: @JockStrap yours is not a button its a link to another page, you need type="submit" etc.. in a button and check status of a checkbox, clicking a link to another page will directly redirect you to that page without checking status of the checkbox. **myCheck** is the id in my answer you can change it to your id.

Answer (score 0):

You can add logic to your clickHandler to check that the box is checked. So instead of calling `getRandomImage()` directly you add some logic to conditionally call the function.

```
function clickHandler() {
  // get the checkbox element from the DOM
  const checkboxElement = document.getElementById('vehicle3');
  // see if the checkbox is checked
  if (checkBoxElement && checkBoxElement.checked) {
    getRandomImage();
  } else {
    console.log("The checkbox wasn't checked!");
  }
}

// add the handler to the button
document.getElementById('generateButton').addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
```

Comment: this doesnt work

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up my syntax. I've edited it so that it should work correctly now.

Comment: look im sorry but this is not explained well enough what am i suppose to add the document.getElementById('generateButton').addEventListener('click', clickHandler); too?? it doesn't work

Comment: You will either need to have the javascript file load with the defer flag or only call the function inside an event listener for the `DOMContentLoaded` event